# Same Data is saving two times?

Tags: php

Hi I'm inserting data to database it's saving two time same data only username is saving two times I want save it only one time also I want save address

```
<?php

    $users = array("username"=>"Kaleem", "adrress"=>"abc");

class dbase{

    public function dbinsert($table,$users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`$key`) VALUES ('$value')";
            $this->conn->query($sql);
            if($this->conn->query($sql))
            {
                echo "Data inserted";
            }
        }
    }

        public function __construct ()
        {

            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbase');

            if($this->conn)
            {
                echo "Connected<br>";
            }
        }


}

$obj = new dbase;
$obj->dbinsert('users',$users);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the query function twice.

```
            $this->conn->query($sql); // saves the first time
            if($this->conn->query($sql)) // saves the second time
            {
                echo "Data inserted";
            }
```

To avoid that the query is called twice you can save the result of the query into a variable and check it in the if.

Currently, you are saving each field of the users array in an own dataset because you are calling the query function on each field from your foreach loop.

Try this:

```
<?php

    $users = array( // this array is for the users
                   array("username"=>"Kaleem", "adrress"=>"abc"), // this is one user
                   array("username"=>"Mickey Mouse", "adrress"=>"Test street"),
                   );

class dbase{

    public function dbinsert($table,$users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
        {
            // Extract field names
            $fields = implode("`, `", array_keys ( $users[$key] );
            // Extract values
            $values = implode("', '", array_values ( $users[$key] );

            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`" . $fields  . "`) VALUES ('". $values ."')";
            // Check if query was succesfull
            $success = $this->conn->query($sql);
            if($success)
            {
                echo "Data inserted";
            } else { // if no success display error message
                echo "Error while saving";
            }
        }
    }

        public function __construct ()
        {

            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbase');

            if($this->conn)
            {
                echo "Connected<br>";
            }
        }


}

$obj = new dbase;
$obj->dbinsert('users',$users);
?>
```

Comment: Username is saving one time but address is not saving

Comment: do you have a field 'adrress' in your table? Because the way it is now it will save each field from the array as an own row. I assume you want to save user name and address in the same row, correct?

Comment: Yeah I have address field in table

Comment: You have added this INSERT INTO $table (`username`, `adrress`) username and address This should be as variable $key because I want it dynamicaly.

Comment: @KaleemBhatti is it now ok,please accept it as answer if it is ok or lets talk in chat.

Answer (score 1):

you need name and address together as column name and corresponding values as field values in sql

```
public function dbinsert($table,$users)
{
    $sqlKeys = []; 
    $sqlValues = [];
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
    {

       $sqlKeys[] = "'".$key."'";
       $sqlValues[] = "'".$value."'";
    }
    $keys = array_implode(",",$sqlKeys);
    $values = array_implode(",",$sqlValues);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($keys) VALUES ($values)";
    if($this->conn->query($sql))
    {
        echo "Data inserted";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

that happen because you using foreach() for single array dimension,

```
$users = ["username"=>"Kaleem", "adrress"=>"abc"];
foreach($users as $key=>$value){
    echo $value."\n";
}
```

this `$success = $this->conn->query($sql);` executed twice because `array` length is `0` and `1` , if you wanna use foreach you  have to use multidimensional array like

```
$users = [
    ["username"=>"Kaleem", "adrress"=>"abc"]
];
foreach($users as $key=>$value){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`username`, `adrress`) VALUES ('". $value['username'] ."', '". $value['adrress'] ."')";
    $this->conn->query($sql);
}
```